# assigning the href tag in code behind with href in aspx page and link inside the cs code

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I want to assign the href link inside the code behind. In order to achieve this. I tried few things like so:

In aspx page:

```
      <a href="#" runat="server" id="Test" onServerClick="MyFuncion_Click">Test1</a>
```

In .cs page, I have this. when I click on test link, nothing happens:

```
  protected void MyFuncion_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

            Test.Attributes["href"] = "http://www.yahoo.com";
        }
```

I want to assign the link only in code behind and define the href in aspx page.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This looks like it would work...but a good question would be why have you written this? The logic of this code appears to be: _"Create a link. When user clicks on the link, change the "href" of the link to something else, and then return to the page."_ . So, what is the idea here? The user must click on it, you set the href, and then they must click on it again to go to the link. That seems strange. What is the reason for that? Or is that not really what you want it to do? It isn't very clear from your question.

Comment: maybe you are trying to redirect the user to another page on click?

Comment: Yes, thats what I am trying to do.

Comment: That would require you to use Response.Redirect